# Detect when .htaccess is being ignored in PHP

Tags: php, apache2

I am looking for a way to detect wether the `Allow override` vhost setting is causing a .htaccess file to be ignored or not.

Right now I am testing against the values of some PHP settings I can set in .htaccess, however this detection isn't good enough (as the values could just as well have been changed in php.ini).

The ultimate goal is to prevent the application to run with ignored .htaccess files for these reasons:

- security;
- anomaly prevention;
- debugging (so far it never was obvious).

Is there a safe and guaranteed way to detect wether .htaccess files are in effect?

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? This is a legitimate question, answered, and helpful to more than myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the .htaccess itself isn't locked down to exclude certain overrides, you can set an environment variable:

```
SetEnv HTACCESS_WORKING here_i_am
```

and check for that in PHP:

```
if (isset($_ENV['HTACCESS_WORKING']) && ($_ENV['HTACESS_WORKING'] === "here_i_am")) {
   ...
}
```

you can be reasonably sure that it's working.

Comment: Yep, this did the trick. Note that getenv() does not trigger an error if an enviroment variable is not set, it just returns false (so your example could be shorter).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a test script as separate to your application, yes.  Have the "security tester" initiate a HTTP request to itself.  You can compare what you sent (acting as the client), to what you get back (when receiving the request).  You will need some sort of communication mechanism between the client side of the script, and the serverside, which is likely to be a different PHP process.  Sessions make this easy.  This will allow you to look at rewrite rules or anything.